# Can I use the idiom 'talk big' this way?

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, idiomatic-language

I just learnt an idiom ' talk big' which means to brag and boast.

what I want to know is when we say someone talks big, does it mean they brag something they already did or something they didn't do.

For example, my friend told me he went bungee jumping yesterday, but actually he didn't. And I know that he is afraid of heights, so can I say he talks big?

Answer (score 1):

*Talking big* refers to something someone is going to do which they may not be able to do, or referring to an exaggeration of what someone has done.

This, however:

> he went bungee jumping yesterday, but actually he didn't.

is outright lying and is not really what *talking big* means.

Comment: could you help me make a dialogue with he likes to talk bigm

Answer (score 0):

"Talking big" is boasting; big talk is a boast.

So the way you are using it is correct because a boast can be either true or false.